# Какой знак препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

В оригинале тут стояла запятая, но мне кажется, что нужно тире или двоеточие: "...ничем свое горе не выдавала(,) ни слезами, ни стонами".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Ничем"* - обобщающее слово, а *"ни слезами, ни стонами"*  раскрывает смысл чем это таким ничем, поэтому надо ставить двоеточие. 
*"...ничем свое горе не выдавала: ни слезами, ни стонами".*